# Shellscript Looping Through All Files in a Folder

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shellscript that will loop through all the files in a folder and echo only the .sql files. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

currently I am getting all the files along with .sql files by running the command

```
 for filename in *; do echo "put ${filename}"; done
```

Also I want to save it in an list or something

Comment: Try `for filename in *.sql; do echo "put ${filename}"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the most compact method:

```
printf "put %s\n" *.sql
```

To save the filenames in an array is equally terse:

```
sqlfiles=(*.sql)
printf "put %s\n" "${sqlfiles[@]}"
```

See [How can I use array variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for more information